# Tensorboard Embedding projector Maximum points showing?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, projector

anyone know does tensorboard embedding only able to show up 100k points only?
Or there is any other way to modify the maximum points show?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out how to do, need to edit the tf-tensorboard.html under directory: /tensorflow/tensorboard/dist/

[image]

Comment: I don't see these lines in the following: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/components/tf_tensorboard/tf-tensorboard.html

Comment: Not find tooooo

Answer (score 0):

As it stands there is no real easy way to do this. The problem is discussed in detail over at GitHub issues [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/725) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/773).